Why does copy/pasting multiple commands from Notepad to CMD cause characters to be lost?
I am testing a python script with multiple images.
I am using argparse python library.
python src\main.py -p 'complete\path\img1.jpg'
python src\main.py -p 'complete\path\img2.jpg'
python src\main.py -p 'complete\path\img3.jpg'
python src\main.py -p 'complete\path\img4.jpg'

I type the above text in a notepad and paste that into terminal.
Ideally, it should work. Invoking main.py with each image.
But what actually happening is, it works alternatively.
like,
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>python src\main.py -p "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Release\IMG_3515.JPG"
expected result, Working...

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\BHUBRCAnalyzer>hon src\main.py  -p "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Release\IMG_3516.JPG"
'hon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>python src\main.py -p "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Release\IMG_3515.JPG"
expected result, Working...

C:\Users\x\Desktop\BHUBRCAnalyzer>hon src\main.py  -p "C:\Users\x\Desktop\Release\IMG_3516.JPG"
'hon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What I have already tried.

Copying from different editor (Notepad and VS Code)
Give an extra new line between the commands

UPDATE: My code looks something like this. The ultralytics module is causing the issue, I am not sure how to avoid this.
This does not occur if I comment out the ultralytics model lines.
from ultralytics import YOLO
import argparse
def main(args:dict):
    model=YOLO()
    model(args['path'])
if __name__=="__main__":
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars="@")
    arg_parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", help="path of the image to get feature", required=True)
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    main(args.__dict__)


There hon is part of the word 'python'. The system did give a correct response. But why does copy paste crop the characters from python-> hon.

maybe your script messes with what is in the clipboard. have you tried making your main.py code just print helloworld and see if the problem persist?

The proper solution is to loop over those images. Change your script so it accepts multiple file arguments, or figure out how to write a for loop in cmd. (I don't particularly recommend the latter.)

What about the -i parameter? Your description does not match your input and does not match the output. Please do not mix random input with random output

About the -i parameter, I forgot to correct them. I have provided a simplified version of the project after debugging.

The Windows Command Processor cmd.exe supports only one type of quoting an argument string like a file or folder name containing a space or one of these characters &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ or literally to interpret <>| like in a password string: ". The character ' has no special meaning for cmd.exe with the exception of set of a for /F loop. The usage of surrounding " lets cmd.exe interpret a space as part of an argument string. Surrounding an argument string in ' as on Linux/Mac is of no help on command line processed by cmd.exe and not a Linux/Mac shell interpreter.

@UDAYKAIPA "This does not occur if I comment out the ultralytics model lines" A great work from you! If you're sure that the ultralytics package is causing the problem, you can report it to them. It might be a bug. The package is a pretty complex pile of code.

It doesn't make sense for the script to have an option if its argument isn't optional.
from ultralytics import YOLO


def main(args: list[str]):
    model=YOLO()
    model(args)


if __name__=="__main__":
    from sys import argv
    main(argv[1:])

This assumes that model can accept multiple file arguments, or perhaps lets you loop over them like
def main(args: list[str]):
    model=YOLO()
    for filename in args:
        model(args)

Usage:
python newscript.py complete\path\img1.jpg complete\path\img2.jpg complete\path\img3.jpg complete\path\img4.jpg


This is not applicable for my project, as images are clicked during runtime for analysis.
I am more curious why this doesn't work? and what exactly is causing this issue. Rather than a work around.
still, I do appreciate the help

That doesn't make sense; why then do you need to copy/paste them from Notepad?
